# XSLT - Combining Information from different Elements/Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a project that I'm working on to learn XML and after trying multiple times and searching for answers online I reached a dead-end.

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" version ="1.0" href='Information Management Project 2.xsl'?>
<task1>
    <normlist>
        <norm>
            <normID>1</normID>
            <name>EN ISO 13857</name>
            <keywords>Security</keywords>
            <keywords>Engines</keywords>
            <replacement />
        </norm>
        <norm>
            <normID>2</normID>
            <name>EN ISO 13849-1</name>
            <keywords>Security</keywords>
            <keywords>Engines</keywords>
            <keywords>Controlling</keywords>
            <replacement>1</replacement>
        </norm>
    </normlist>
    <puplicationlist>
        <title>
            <name>Norms for Engine Security</name>
            <filename>caise2011sgln.pfd</filename>
            <normIDREFS>1 2</normIDREFS>
        </title>
        <title>
            <name>Setting up Complex Engines</name>
            <filename>coopis2012sln.pdf</filename>
            <normIDREFS>2</normIDREFS>
        </title>
    </puplicationlist>
</task1>
```

Now I need to come up with an XSLT that shows the following:
The first column contains the norm name, the second column contains the file names of the publications referring to the norm.

Something like that: [image]

I tried it with different approaches but non of them worked and in the end I always get displayed just the norm names:

[image]

Example attempt with Key():

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name='norm2publication' match='task1/normlist/norm' use= 'normID'/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
          <table>
             <tr>
                <td>Norm</td>
                <td>Publications</td>
             </tr>
             <xsl:for-each select='task1/normlist/norm'>
             <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select='name'/> </td>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('norm2publication', 'task1/publicationlist/title/normIDREFS')/filename">
                    <td><xsl:value-of select='task1/publicationlist/title/filename'/> </td> 
                </xsl:for-each>          
             </tr>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For reasons of space I paste the other attempts as an image:

normID=normIDREFS: [image]

variable: [image]

What do I need to change in the XSLT to get the expected result?

Comment: 1. Please edit your question and add the expected result. 2. Do a search regarding performing XSLT in a browser.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks for your reply. I just updated the expected result with a picture to illustrate the expected outcome. The question still is what needs to be changed to get to this outcome.

Comment: Please do not use images and external links instead of code embedded in the question itself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your input XML is very inconvenient for what you want to do (at least in pure XSLT 1.0). Apparently, the authors intended to take advantage of the  [ID/IDREFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4lZq.png)  feature - however, this can work only if the XML document has a DTD and the XSLT processor knows how to read it.

Without this, you need to find a way to match a `normID` to a `normIDREFS` which may contain multiple values in a space-delimited string. You cannot use a *key* for this, unless you tokenize the string first. Since XSLT 1.0 does not have a `tokenize()` function (though some processors support extension functions for this), I suggest you try this primitive approach instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/task1">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Norm</th>
                    <th>Publications</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="normlist/norm">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//puplicationlist/title[contains(concat(' ', normIDREFS, ' '), concat(' ', current()/normID, ' '))]" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="filename"/>
                                <br/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Norm</th>
            <th>Publications</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>EN ISO 13857</td>
            <td>caise2011sgln.pfd<br></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>EN ISO 13849-1</td>
            <td>caise2011sgln.pfd<br>coopis2012sln.pdf<br></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Rendered as:

[image]